# Oracle 11g RAC - PSU

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rac, oracle-grid-control

Simple question, when patching two nodes of 11g RDBMS, do I need to patch GRID as well, or only RDMBS is enough?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

https://mikedietrichde.com/2017/04/26/keep-your-patch-versions-between-grid-infrastructure-and-databases-homes-in-synch/

> Can you have different PSU/BP versions between Database and GI homes?
>   Yes, you can have a higher version PSU or BP in the Database home than
>   in the Grid Infrastructure home managing the resources. This is
>   implicitly documented in MOS Note 337737.1 – Oracle Clusterware
>   (CRS/GI) – ASM – Database Version Compatibility where it says:
>
> “The Oracle Grid Infrastructure (GI) /Clusterware (CRS) version must
>   be of the highest version down to the 4th digit in the possible
>   combinations at all times.“
>
> Therefore you can deviate that this rule does not apply for the 5th
>   digit anymore.

Comment: If you are on RAC you can do it in a rolling fashion, if you have a standby you can do it with a minimal downtime. On single database, you need a downtime. Oracle patch instructions offer multiple suggestions How to do the patching